# I'm not receiving firebase notifications on my iOS Device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not receiving Firebase Notifications on my iOS Device. I have tried changing many aspects of the code to no avail. I also tried to run the app on both a simulator and a phone but it the notify don't show up on either. I am following Firebase Documentation but it's still not working. Here's my AppDelegate File:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
           SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }



        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()



        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }


}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}

extension AppDelegate:MessagingDelegate {

 func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Message Data:  ", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the firebase documentation and also the configuration of iOS certificates?

Comment: First thing first. You will not receive notification in simulator always test with actual device. Are you sending notification from google console?

Comment: @Faysal Ahmed, yes I'm following firebase documentation and have configured the iOS certificates. Krunal Nagvadia Yep, I'm testing on an actual device and sending the notifs from my Firebase Console!

Comment: Check your plist, Bundle and Configure certificate match with your project. If still not work then please create new project in your console and repeat reach process step by step. I see sometimes google trouble with configure with iOS app.

Also add correct `GoogleService-Info.plist` and allow notification in your device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling Push Notifications :-

I'm posting this solution as it worked for me.But before use this please do check that you have uploaded right APNs authentication key under iOS app configuration on console.
- Go to your AppDelegate file.
- Step 1: Write this code inside this function:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var application : UIApplication?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        _ = (deviceToken as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: CChar.self, capacity: deviceToken.count)
        var token = ""
        token = /Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("FCM token: \(token )")
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Did Fail to Register for Remote Notifications")
        print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        print("didReceiveRemoteNotification \(userInfo)")
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        print("======== messafe received %@", userInfo)

       //handle push notification

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    @available(iOS 10, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
        case .active:

            break
        case .background, .inactive :

            let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

           //handle push notification
            break

        default:

            break
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

    func performNotificationAction(userInfo : [AnyHashable : Any], completion : (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> ()) {


        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {

        }

        else if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {

        }
    }

    func pushNavigation(userInfo : [AnyHashable : Any], completion : (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> ()) {


    }
}
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    public func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {


    }

    public func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        print(fcmToken)
    }
}
```

Comment: It says "Use of unresolved identifier 'ApplicationDelegate'

Comment: you can use SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

Comment: The error disappeared, but the problem still persists. I will check and let you know!